# Something wrong here with this code

Tags: excel, vba

My input box wont clear after I make my selection. What am I doing wrong or can this be better written.

```
    Do
   Response = True
    inputData = InputBox("Type 'ID' for Impaired Driving/e-Lap, or 'OP' for Occupant Protection:", "Impaired/e-Lap or Occupant Protection Selection")


    If inputData = "ID" Then
        FrmImpairedDriving.Show
        Else
        Response = False
    End If
    If inputData = "id" Then
        FrmImpairedDriving.Show
        Else
        Response = False
    End If
    If inputData = "OP" Then
        FrmOccupantProtection.Show
        Else
        Response = False
    End If
    If inputData = "op" Then
        FrmOccupantProtection.Show
    Else
        Response = False
    End If
Loop Until Response = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim inputData as String = InputBox("Type 'ID' for Impaired Driving/e-Lap, or 'OP' for Occupant Protection:", "Impaired/e-Lap or Occupant Protection Selection")
```

also look into `Select Case`. It is easier than using so many if statments.  Also use `Ucase` to compare than you can get rid of trying twice for the same response.